# Order letters in ascending order read in from a text file in Java

Tags: java, string

***I have had help with this code, full credit to the creator***

I'm trying to make a Java class that displays how many times a letter appears within a text file and display them in ascending order so if the text file contains `Hello World`, the output would be

```
D is shown 1 time
E is shown 1 time
H is shown 1 time
L is shown 3 times
O is shown 2 times
R is shown 1 time
W is shown 1 time
```

However, with the code that I have, it does display the letters and how many times they get displayed, but instead of them being grouped together like shown above, it gets displayed as if:

```
E is shown 1 time
H is shown 1 time
L is shown 2 times
O is shown 1 time
W is shown 1 time
L is shown 1 time
O is shown 1 time
R is shown 1 time
D is shown 1 time
```

The code (which is not mine as stated at the beginning) which I'm looking to modify so that its output is similar to the first example is

```
public class class1{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("example.txt"))) {
        while (in.hasNext()) {
                letterFrequency(in.next());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void letterFrequency(String input) {
        Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
        for (char each : input.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(each)) {
                char upper = Character.toUpperCase(each);
                counts.put(upper, counts.getOrDefault(upper, 0) + 1);
            }
        }
        counts.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
            System.out.println(String.format(String.format("%s is shown %d "
                + "time%s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(),
                entry.getValue() > 1 ? "s" : "")));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand what the code does, and why it displays the output that way, you'd better learn what [a Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is, and restart from scratch, by thinking about your own algorithm. Hint: a TreeMap would be helpful. Read its documentation.

Comment: Use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` to get keys (letters) sorted. Instead of calling `letterFrequency()` for each word, call it for the entire text *or* make the map last across multiple invocations, either by passing it in as a parameter, or by making it a field (requires changing code to non-static methods).

Comment: Your input is being processed one word at a time, not one line at a time.  So it is printing out the letter counts in "Hello", and then it is printing out the letter counts in "World".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are processing **one word at a time**.

Your counting algorithm is OK (except for output order). Your problem is with the Scanner, which reads one word at a time.

Change the scanner to read in the whole file, passing that to your counting method. One (sneaky) way is to do this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("example.txt")).useDelimiter("\\A")
```

which sets the delimiter to the start of all input, which of course never happens (again) so it keeps reading to the end of the stream.

One interesting and convenient outcome of using `"\\A"` as the delimiter is that if the input is empty, `hasNext()` is `false`, so this change will also automatically handle empty files cleanly.

You can fix the order of the output of the letters just by using a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: `\\A` Very sneaky.

Comment: Though a better implementation would be to use a plain `char[]` buffer and accumulate all results in the Map, delaying the printing until end-of-file. This will perform better (`Scanner` is insanely slow), and allow unlimited file size without running out of memory.

Comment: @Andreas and it handles empty files automatically by returning `false` from `hasNext()` in that case.

Comment: Actually, the "`\\A` very sneaky trick" is terrible.  `while (in.hasNext()) {` is clearly starting a loop, to call `letterFrequency(...)` multiple times.  This trick obfuscates the code, forcing the loop to execute no more than once.  It would not pass any sane code review.  `while(in.hasNextLine())` and `letterFrequence(in.nextLine())` is probably what the OP intended ... and is not "sneaky, tricky" code.

Comment: @ajn is that so... Using `"\\A"` has identical behaviour to the (very popular) apache [`Filetils.readFileToString()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File)), and I use this "trick" in my production code (albeit behind a utility method similar to apache's) and it works just fine. As long as you know this idiom reads the entire file, it's OK in my book.

Comment: @Bohemian My objection is not to `\\A` but to the combination of `\\A` and `while(in.hasNext()) {...}`.  It looks like a while-loop but effectively is only an if-statement; it can only execute at most one time.  Someone reading the code after the fact may erroneously expect the loop to execute more than once.  In an obfuscated-Java contest, this is a wonderful trick to have in the toolbox, but for maintainable code, `\\A` and `while(in.hasNext()) {...}` do **not** belong together.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the set of all characters, turn it into an array, sort said array, and then go through values in that order. Something along the lines of:

```
Character[] keys = counts.keySet().toArray();
java.util.Arrays.sort(keys)
for(Character key : keys) {
    // Do something with key and counts.get(key) for character and frequency respectively.
}
```

As for the problem relating to reading word at a time versus the whole file:

You should break your function up into two parts, the part that counts stuff and the part that displays stuff. Something like this:

```
private static Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
private static void countLetterFrequency(String input) {
    for (char each : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(each)) {
            char upper = Character.toUpperCase(each);
            counts.put(upper, counts.getOrDefault(upper, 0) + 1);
        }
    }
}
private static void displayLetterFrequency() {
    Character[] keys = counts.keySet().toArray();
    java.util.Arrays.sort(keys)
    for(Character key : keys) {
        System.out.println(String.format(String.format("%s is shown %d "
            + "time%s", key, counts.get(key),
            counts.get(key) > 1 ? "s" : "")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing to a `TreeMap` would be much simpler.

Comment: If you want to write up an answer go for it, just don't be a douche and down vote mine because I answered first.

Comment: Sorry, you also only answered half the question. Doesn't cover why letters are repeated in output.

Comment: Yeah, I guess he does have a second part. He never really states what's wrong so I didn't catch that he had two problems.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the space for which you can access the entire file at once or pass the map again as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("example.txt"))) {
    while (in.hasNext()) {
            letterFrequency(in.next(), counts);
        }
    }

    counts.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
        System.out.println(String.format(String.format("%s is shown %d "
            + "time%s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(),
            entry.getValue() > 1 ? "s" : "")));
    });
}

private static Map<Character, Integer> letterFrequency(String input, Map<Character, Integer> counts) {
    for (char each : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(each)) {
            char upper = Character.toUpperCase(each);
            counts.put(upper, counts.getOrDefault(upper, 0) + 1);
        }
    }
    return counts;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get a sorted list by keys using `TreeMap`

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

Comment: Only half an answer. Doesn't cover why letters are repeated in output.